# Counting the sql records on the basis of date in BIRT

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, birt

I have a table in sql for records. It contains dateTime,id and some other columns.
I want to show in line graph the number of records increased or decreased each month.

Date and Time in SQL is in this format : 2016-03-22 16:09:50.0000000
Data type of this column in sql server is 'datetime2(0)'

At the moment I am putting 'dateTime' in x-axis and 'id' on y-axis. I think I can use id to count the records per month.

Here is the screenshot of the out put report.

[image]

Time is not showing up in the proper format and I have no idea how can I count the records for each month.

Please help .. Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: What is your query, how did you get that graph? A `datetime` does not have a format. Also, mysql != sql server, please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @HoneyBadger sorry my mistake on the wrong tag.. I have edited it now.. My query is simple I am getting all the records from the table at the moment. select * from mytable and on x axis I am setting the dateTime column and on y axis I am setting up the id.

Comment: If you want a count of records, you should probably select `count()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a data set which has the count of ID, and a varchar field of year/month, something like:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(year(yourdatetimefield), '-', month(yourdatetimefield)) AS YearMonth,
COUNT (ID) AS COUNT
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CONCAT(year(yourdatetimefield), '-', month(yourdatetimefield))
```

This returns a year/month, and the number of IDs in each month.